# How to save data from dataframe to json file?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

How can I convert to Json file form Dataframe in python using pandas.
I don't know how to get name and carmodel column, I was only get the price from dataframe

I have an Dataframe like:

```
name   carmodel 
ACURA  CL           6.806155e+08
       OTHER        2.280000e+08
       EL           1.300000e+08
       MDX          7.828750e+08
       RDX          3.850000e+08
                        ...
VOLVO  XC90         3.748778e+09
ZOTYE  OTHER        1.887500e+08
       HUNTER       1.390000e+08
       T600         4.200000e+08
       Z8           4.754000e+08
```

so I want to convert it like:

```
{
    'ACURA': 
        {
            'CL':6.806155e+08,
            'OTHER':2.280000e+08,
            'MDX':7.828750e+08,
        },
        
    'VOLVO':
        {
            'XC90':3.748778e+09,
        },
    'ZOTYE':
        {
            'OTHER':1.887500e+08,
            'HUNTER':1.390000e+08,
            'T600':4.200000ee+08,
        }
}
```

Here is my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'D:\vucar\scraper\result.csv',dtype='unicode')
df['price'] = pd.to_numeric(df['price'],downcast='float')
cars = df[['name','carmodel','price']].sort_values('name').groupby(['name','carmodel']).mean()['price']
print(cars)
```

Comment: It not work  for me, the output like: {"('name1','carmodel1')":price1,('name2','carmodel2')":price2,...}

Comment: yes, the multiindex complicates things, I've posted a different answer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reset the index on cars, then groupby `name` again, while merging `carmodel` and `name` to a dictionary, then save as json:

```
cars = df[['name','carmodel','price']].sort_values('name').groupby(['name','carmodel']).mean().reset_index(level='carmodel')
cars.groupby('name').apply(lambda x: x.set_index('carmodel')['price'].to_dict()).to_json('filename.json', orient='index')
```

output:

```
{"ACURA":{"CL":680615500.0,"EL":130000000.0,"MDX":782875000.0,"OTHER":228000000.0,"RDX":385000000.0},"VOLVO":{"XC90":3748778000.0},"ZOTYE":{"HUNTER":139000000.0,"OTHER":188750000.0,"T600":420000000.0,"Z8":475400000.0}}
```